# How to extract value from a scala Future

Tags: scala, dictionary, future, rediscala

How to I perform a reduce/fold operation on the Seq and then get the final value.

I'm performing an operation (in this case a Redis call) that returns a Future. I'm processing the Future (results) using a map operation.

The map operation returns a Future[Seq[Any]] type.

```
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[Any]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@269f8f79
```

Now I want to perform some operations(fold/reduce) on this Seq and then get a final value. How can I achieve this?

```
  implicit val akkaSystem = akka.actor.ActorSystem()
  val redisClient = RedisClient()
  val sentimentZSetKey = "dummyzset"
  val currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val end = Limit(currentTimeStamp)
  val start = Limit(currentTimeStamp - 60 * 100000)
  val results = redisClient.zrangebyscoreWithscores(ZSetKey, start, end)
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
  import org.json4s.DefaultFormats


  results.map {
    seq => seq.map {
      element => element match {

        case (byteString, value) => {
          val p = byteString.decodeString("UTF-8")
          try {
            val ph = parse(p).extract[MyClass]
            ph

          } catch {
            case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage)
          }
        }
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking is [discouraged](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking) when using futures in Scala, but it can be done with the `Await` function as per the link. Since you want to further transform the sequence, you are better off using functional composition as in [these examples](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional_composition_and_forcomprehensions).